# AWS - 32 bit windows Amazon EC2 machine - can't RDP

Tags: windows, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I have a 32 bit Windows Machine on AWS ec2, All of a sudden From last weekend I haven't been able to RDP to my machine, the machine is overworked always but it was never a case that i couldn't log in to it.

I have been running this same machine since past few months, and it never refused a RDP, the security groups haven't been touched.

The only option now i have is to make a new machine (but as 32 bit machine can't be scaled) I can't make AMI of this machine and boot with it, I'll just have to make a new machine from ground up.

The issue actually is the RDP, if only i could do that it'll help me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

This trick has saved me a few times. If you don't know if the machine is live or not... use these steps.

1. Find the public IP address of your local machine (PC you are on).
2. In the **AWS EC2 Dashboard**, find the **security group** attached to your VPS/EC2.
3. Add a rule for inbound/outbound ALL Traffic to/from *your* IP address to the public address of the EC2. Save/apply all changes
4. Ping the public IP address of your EC2 machine from command prompt. If you get a response...it is still alive. Let's try and connect to it.

If no response, your machine is dead. Try a force reboot from the EC2 Dashboard and check for System Check errors. If none, ping again and proceed.

5. Create an Elastic IP from your dashboard (free for 1). This is a public IP address that you can "attach" to machines.
6. Create a network interface and connect it to your EC2 machine. This will use the Elastic IP you just created.
7. Allow time to pass for the NIC to install.
8. Use remote desktop connection and connect to the Elastic IP address.

You should now be able to connect to your machine through RDP if this was a network problem.

I have had to use this trick a few times running VPN tunnels and creating virtual active directory domains if I fudged up the network details. Just in case the default Public IP address is not accessible, this provides you a second public IP to attempt connection to the machine.

Good luck.

Comment: Hi, My machine is already on a public ip, the reboots, the stop and start are just not helping me, even the AWS support says its better that I rather start making another machine with the backup